# What is the relation of protobuf message field id and field order?

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, field, message

I want to understand if the messages bellow are compatible from the perspective of protobuf and serialization/deserialization.

```
message HelloReply {
  string message = 1;
  string personalized_message = 2;
}
```

```
message HelloReply {
  string personalized_message = 2;
  string message = 1;
}
```

Does the order matter for compatibility in any situation?

Comment: The whole point of the numbers is to [identify the field](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3#assigning_field_numbers) in the binary message, so these messages should be compatible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The textual order is largely irrelevant, although it may impact some code generation tooling - but most languages don't care about declaration order, so even that: won't matter. The fields are still defined semantically equivalent - the numbers match the existing meaning (name) and type. It is the number that is the determining feature in identifying a field.

At the protocol level:

- parsers *must* allow fields in any order
- serializers *should* (but not *must*) write fields in ascending numerical field order

Comment: I've just found the reference documentation of this: https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/encoding#order